# Domain name returning DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on certain networks or internet providers

Tags: resolv

I have a domain which returns PROB_DNS_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN when i try to access it from a certain network. I used cloudflare nameservers and still didnt work on the one network, used namecheap hosting and pointed the domain namecheap nameservers and still got the nxdomain from the same network, used godaddy hosting and afrihost and still no luck. The site opens up well on other networks, even when the domain is set to default ns it still returns nxdomain when using that one network.. Thank you all in advance.

I changed the browser DNS settings to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 and it works on the same network but for other people using the same network always find the nxdomain error. I was wondering if there is a way I could fix this issue via SSH so that other people using the vodacom network can also gain easy access to the site without having to manually configure DNS servers on their devices.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that you have pointed your domain to correct IP address? Since you use Cloudflare name server, you can also test to disable the proxy first.

Comment: The IP address I am pointing is correct, what bothers me now is that even when it is parked it still returns the nxdomain error when I try to access it using Vodacom network. the site is PayMeBucks.co.za I have placed it under maintenance mode at the moment.